# Issue running EF Core 7 Migration in docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to run Entity Framework Core 7 migrations in a Docker container and not being very successful at the moment.

I am following this tutorial :

https://dotnetthoughts.net/docker-compose-asp-net-core-application/

In my case, I am using MySql instead of SQL Server. My database is running on the host computer instead of a container.

[image]

I think that the issue is that some of the steps in the tutorial are for linux systems and I am using Windows.

How can I adapt these two files for a Windows environment?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TodoApi.csproj", "./"]
COPY Setup.sh Setup.sh

RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

RUN dotnet restore "./TodoApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."

RUN /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef migrations add InitialMigrations

RUN chmod +x ./Setup.sh
CMD /bin/bash ./Setup.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

until /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef database update --no-build; do
>&2 echo "SQL Server is starting up"
sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "SQL Server is up - executing command"

/root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef database update
```

Edit # 1.

Here's my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Meerkat.WebService/Meerkat.WebService.csproj", "./"]
COPY ["Meerkat.Application/Meerkat.Application.csproj", "./Application"]
COPY ["Meerkat.Domain/Meerkat.Domain.csproj", "./Domain"]
COPY ["Meerkat.Infrastructure/Meerkat.Infrastructure.csproj", "./Infrastructure"]

COPY Meerkat.WebService/Setup.sh Meerkat.WebService/Setup.sh

RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

RUN dotnet restore "./Meerkat.WebService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."

RUN /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef migrations add InitialMigrations

RUN chmod +x Meerkat.WebService/Setup.sh
CMD /bin/bash Meerkat.WebService/Setup.sh
```

I now have a couple of issues here:

The following statement

```
RUN dotnet restore "./Meerkat.WebService.csproj"
```

generates this warning:

[image]

which is surprising because the copy operation above it executes without issue.

The following statement also fails with an error message this time:

```
RUN /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef migrations add InitialMigrations
```

Here's the message:

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: _"How can I adapt these two files for a Windows environment?"_ - but why? You are using docker - you can use linux containers.

Comment: Hi @GuruStron, I am actually using Linux containers.

Any ideas what the cause of the error may be?  All the files are in the project directory

Comment: Can you post full [mre] somewhere?

Comment: Do you just want to run migrations on every deployment, or is there a reason you want run migrations seperately? You could include code to run Migrations on startup in the .NET Core Program.cs file of your application

Comment: As for the error message: Is your Dockerfile correctly named? What do your docker compose files look like?

Comment: Hi @JineappleAra, Thanks for the reply.  I have to run the migration separately for scalability reason when several copies of the service are run.

Comment: I have made some progress since I last posted. It turned out that some paths in the dockerfile were incorrect. Now I have ran into new issues when the "restore" statement is called in the dockerfile.  I will update the original post to explain further. Thanks

Comment: Hi @GuruStron, I will provide the example as soon as I figure out how to do it.

Comment: I am now getting the following error message on the migration step:    
 meerkatservice-migrations-1           |  ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.    Am I missing something in my dockerfile?  Like a reference to Mysql driver?

Comment: The issue with the restore statement seems to be you're copying files to different paths than what the Webservice.csproj expects (Renaming the directory).
For the rest, please post the full files (docker compose, db connection string, etc.)

Comment: Have you tried executing the add-migration manually after deployment?

Comment: Hi @QiangFu, I ended up doing something similar. I generated SQL scripts from the migrations data and manually executed them after deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to made the process simple and it succeed. Needn't another "migration.dockerfile" and bash.
Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["testapi.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./testapi.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.25
RUN /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef migrations add InitialCreate --project testapi.csproj -v
RUN /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef database update

WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "testapi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "testapi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "testapi.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  todoapi:
    image: testapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 30002:80
```

[image]